# How can I prevent code in Windows.Forms OnDeactivate running when hitting a breakpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

For example: create a new Windows.Forms project and give it a button. Add the following code:

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDeactivate(e);
    Debug.WriteLine("deactivated");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

As expected, the output window displays "hello" when the button is clicked, and "deactivated" when some other window is activated.

Now, place a breakpoint on the Debug.Writeline("hello"). Click the button, then resume execution. Notice that the output window shows both "hello" and "deactivated".

I would like to find a way to prevent this, so that debugging my app does not change its behavior any more than necessary. Just as when the breakpoint is not present, the click handler should run but the deactivate one should not.

It would be ideal to find a setting in Visual Studio such that hitting a breakpoint does not fire the deactivate event in the app at all. I have not found such a setting.

It would be acceptable to find a way to know that the application being activated in place of mine is Visual Studio (better: that it is some debugging tool...this program might well be debugged using Visual Studio Code or Mono Develop). Then I could code OnDeactivate not to do the deactivate behavior in that case.

It is possible to set an Action on a breakpoint that will set a flag in the program that prevents the action. This is a very undesirable solution because every programmer must remember to do it every time they create a breakpoint where the deactivate action is not wanted.

Remote debugging is another potential solution; but I don't want to have to do all my debugging using another system.

(Note: in the real app, what happens on deactivate is to save what the user is editing. The problem is that when I'm in the middle of debugging something else an unexpected Save can mess things up. Data may not be in a valid state to save.)

Comment: Would it be enough to check for `Debugger.IsAttached` ? You wouldn't be able to run code in `OnDeactivated` while debugging.

Comment: Use a preprocessor directive : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: Using Debugger.IsAttached is an interesting possibility. The downside is not getting the Deactivate behavior when the window is deactivated normally (as opposed to by a breakpoint). But it could be removed when actually debugging that functionality, and yet enable debugging code that the deactivate interferes with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting with the preprocessor directive. I could use #if !DEBUG or just #if false to disable the Deactivate code for a particular debugging session, but that isn't distinguishing breakpoint deactivates from others.

Answer (score 0):

You've said *"Remote debugging is another potential solution; but I don't want to have to do all my debugging using another system."* (which I'm guessing also rules out using a VM).

My suggestion would be to become less dependent upon debugging the running application by writing Unit Tests. With Unit Tests, you can test isolated parts of your system independently of others.

When you have Unit Tests in place you can run each individual test under Debug, allowing you to step through the code exactly like you do when debugging the application; but since you get to define the scope of the test, the whole application isn't running, so things like the application losing focus can be made out out of scope.

Once a test is in place, it can shorten the time taken by the code+debug iteration cycle, making you more productive. It achieves that because the test fires you straight into the relevant code with the test scenario already set up, rather than the whole application having to start up, and you navigating through to the relevant parts each time to get into the scenario you want.

Another benefit of these tests (if they are written the right way) is that you can make them run as part of an automated build which is triggered whenever someone changes some code. This means that if anyone breaks that code, the test will fail, and the build will fail.

Comment: Makes sense, and we have a large collection of unit tests running automatically. But it is very difficult to adequately unit-test a large program that is mostly GUI, and there are still bugs we need to work on in the full system.